# IList as dependency property, setter does not seem to be working

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have the following custom user control that derives from `ComboBox`:

```
public class EnumSourceComboBox : ComboBox
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ExcludedItemsProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(
            "ExcludedItems", 
            typeof(IList), 
            typeof(EnumSourceComboBox), 
            new PropertyMetadata(
                new List<object>()));

    public EnumSourceComboBox()
    {
        this.ExcludedItems = new List<object>();
    }

    public IList ExcludedItems
    {
        get
        {
            return (IList)this.GetValue(EnumSourceComboBox.ExcludedItemsProperty);
        }

        set
        {
            this.SetValue(EnumSourceComboBox.ExcludedItemsProperty, value);
        }
    }
}
```

and I use it in `XAML` as follows:

```
        <controls:EnumSourceComboBox>
            <controls:EnumSourceComboBox.ExcludedItems>
                <employeeMasterData:TaxAtSourceCategory>FixedAmount</employeeMasterData:TaxAtSourceCategory>
                <employeeMasterData:TaxAtSourceCategory>FixedPercentage</employeeMasterData:TaxAtSourceCategory>
            </controls:EnumSourceComboBox.ExcludedItems>
        </controls:EnumSourceComboBox>
```

This builds fine and there's no `XAML` parse exception or something similar. However, the `ExcludedItems` always have `count == 0`, so the two items defined in `XAML` are not added to the list.

How do you define a dependency property to support this behavior?

**Update**: Here's the `TaxAtSourceCategory` enumeration:

```
public enum TaxAtSourceCategory
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The none.
    /// </summary>
    None, 

    /// <summary>
    /// The fixed amount.
    /// </summary>
    FixedAmount, 

    /// <summary>
    /// The fixed percentage.
    /// </summary>
    FixedPercentage, 

    // Has some more values, but I don't think that matters
}
```

Comment: One big mistake is that you set the default value to `new List<object>()`, this means that ALL instances of `EnumSourceComboBox` refer to the one instance of `Linst<object>`. A, i see you're creating it also in the constructor. you can remove the default value

Comment: Thanks, you are right of course, however the constructor creates a new instance anyway, so I don't think that is the problem (and removing it in the Register call does not fix it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the following code there is the EnumSourceCombobox with the tracking of the changes in the collection.
There are both tracking of :
-the collection change (collection replaced with another on)
-and changes in the collection ( add/remove/clear)

```
public class EnumSourceComboBox : ComboBox
{
    private ObservableCollection<TaxAtSourceCategory> previousCollection;

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ExcludedItemsProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(
            "ExcludedItems",
            typeof(ObservableCollection<TaxAtSourceCategory>),
            typeof(EnumSourceComboBox),
            new PropertyMetadata(null));
    public ObservableCollection<TaxAtSourceCategory> ExcludedItems
    {
        get
        {
            return (ObservableCollection<TaxAtSourceCategory>)this.GetValue(EnumSourceComboBox.ExcludedItemsProperty);
        }
        set
        {
            this.SetValue(EnumSourceComboBox.ExcludedItemsProperty, value);
        }
    }
    public EnumSourceComboBox()
    {
        DependencyPropertyDescriptor dpd = DependencyPropertyDescriptor.FromProperty(EnumSourceComboBox.ExcludedItemsProperty, typeof(EnumSourceComboBox));
        dpd.AddValueChanged(this, (o, e) =>
        {
            if (previousCollection != null)
                previousCollection.CollectionChanged -= ExcludedItemsChanged;
            previousCollection = ExcludedItems;
            if (previousCollection != null)
                previousCollection.CollectionChanged += ExcludedItemsChanged;
        });
        this.ExcludedItems = new ObservableCollection<TaxAtSourceCategory>();
    }
    void ExcludedItemsChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Take into account change in the excluded items more seriously !
        MessageBox.Show("CollectionChanged to count " + ExcludedItems.Count);
    }
}
```

Here is a link to the solution :
http://1drv.ms/1P8cMVc

Best use

Answer (score 1):

@cguedel,

I tried your DependencyProperty code, and it runs fine. 
I added two strings in the XAML content of the property instead of `TaxAtSourceCategory` instances
In the Loaded event of the window I had a count for the list of 2.

So may be you ve got Something to do with the `TaxAtSourceCategory` class.
And may be you could show the `TaxAtSourceCategory` code, check the constructor call...

Regards

Comment: I've got a unit tests that also works (values are excluded), just a sec, I will include the TaxAtSourceCategory enum.

Comment: Just created the enum TaxAtSourceCategory{FixedAmount,FixedPercentage} .and it works

Comment: I think I've found the problem: the PropertyChangedCallback handler for the ExcludedItems property is not fired when new items are added, so I never observe the new items in the logic to exclude them when the property changes. Update: Sure enough, that was the problem!

Comment: If you want to have the add/remove events, you should declare  your Collection as an ObservableCollection<TaxAtSourceCategory>. The events from the dependency property will be called only when you change the value of the property collection (set a new collection). Then you should subscribe manually to the collection (in the code of your control) or put some databinding on your collection. good luck